# Inserting multiple values between daterange into DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, razor, webmatrix

i have a form which collects 2 dates (start date & end date) in the format mm/dd/yyyy

I want to collect these 2 dates from the form, and then create a list of all dates between these 2 days, then insert them into seperate rows in mt database. Here is my code:

```
if(IsPost){
    var bookedFrom = Request.Form["dateFrom"];
    var bookedTo = Request.Form["dateTo"];

    DateTime dateF = Convert.ToDateTime(bookedFrom);
    DateTime dateT = Convert.ToDateTime(bookedTo);

    var dates = new List<DateTime>();

    for (var dt = dateF; dt <= dateT; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
    {
       dates.Add(dt);
    }

    foreach(var dat in dates){
        db.Execute("INSERT INTO Property_Availability (PropertyID, BookedDate, BookedNotes, BookedType) VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3)", rPropertyId, dat, Request.Form["BookedNotes"], Request.Form["BookedType"]);
    }
}
```

However, when i try and post my form, i get the following error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
>   DateTime dateF = Convert.ToDateTime(bookedFrom);

Any idea where i'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: examine the value of bookedFrom, what does it have in it?  Not what are you putting into the field on the web form, but what goes into this variable in the first couple of lines of the code you show here?

Comment: Look into using [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Convert.ToDateTime does a DateTime.Parse, in this case, using the current culture format.  For DateTime.ParseExact, you have to provide the format provider, and it will be more strict about matching that.  I don't think  that will help.

Comment: Use the unambiguous `yyyy-MM-dd` format instead of the locale-specific (and US only) `mm/dd/yyyy`. `DateTime.Parse("2015-12-13")` will work in any locale and return December 13,  2015

Comment: What is your `bookedFrom` _exactly_? What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just my 2 cents in help you out, also consider using debug to know whether what values are passed / etc.

```
 if(IsPost){
    DateTime pFrom = new DateTime();
    DateTime pTo = new DateTime();

    var bookedFrom = Request.Form["dateFrom"];
    var bookedTo = Request.Form["dateTo"];

    if(DateTime.TryParse(bookedFrom, out pFrom) && DateTime.TryParse(bookedTo, out pTo))
    {
        DateTime dateF = pFrom;
        DateTime dateT = pTo;

        var dates = new List<DateTime>();

        for (var dt = dateF; dt <= dateT; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
        {
           dates.Add(dt);
        }

        foreach(var dat in dates){
            db.Execute("INSERT INTO Property_Availability (PropertyID, BookedDate, BookedNotes, BookedType) VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3)", rPropertyId, dat, Request.Form["BookedNotes"], Request.Form["BookedType"]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Invalid date from : " + bookedFrom + " and date to : " + bookedTo + "');</script>"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on your exception, you have some problems with format of Request.Form["dateFrom"] value.

For example date in your default locale is supposed to be in format 'dd/mm/yyyy' or something like that.

So if you exactly know format of date in this parameter it's better to use something like that

```
DateTime dateF = DateTime.ParseExact(bookedFrom, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Instead of the non-standard US format, it's better to use the ISO 8601 format `yyyy-MM-dd`